# How to organize large set of database tables in ERD diagram?

Tags: erd

Say for e.g. I have 100 of tables in a database and I use SQL Server 2008 to generate the `ERD` diagram for me. How can I logically group the related tables so that at one glance user will only see the portion they want to see rather than the whole lot of tables in the database relationship?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can create more than one diagram, showing the various areas of your database

Comment: Is there any suggestion on how to link up between the various diagrams?